# Javascript - Go through textfield and search for values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, formatting

I might be overthinking this, but I have a web application where there's a text field containing css code as text. I want to programatically look for values containing # values and pass those through a function. So far I've split each line into an array and I can loop through that array to find those values and successfully pass them to the lighten or darken function. Works great!

However, the formatting is wrong and I'm not sure if I've been overthinking this whole thing or if I'm on the right track.

I've got a jsbin here: https://jsbin.com/koquqapoyi/edit?html,js,output

This is the js code:

```
function lighten() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var arrText = text.split("\n");
  var lightArr = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
      var noHex = arrText[i].split('#');
      lightArr.push(noHex);
  }
  
  
    for (var i = 0; i < lightArr.length; i++) {
    if (lightArr[i].length == 2) {
     lightArr[i][1] = '#' + LightenDarkenColor(lightArr[i][1], 20);
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("newColors").value = lightArr;
  
}


function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
  col = parseInt(col, 16);
  return (((col & 0x0000FF) + amt) | ((((col >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt) << 8) | (((col >> 16) + amt) << 16)).toString(16);
}
```

Notice how the output in the second text field is all messed up in formatting. I want it to look exactly like the other text field, only with altered colors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..
Just needed these few lines:

```
  lightArr = lightArr.toString();
  lightArr = lightArr.split(',$').join('\n');
  lightArr = lightArr.split(',/').join('\n');
  lightArr = lightArr.split(',#').join('#');
```